# Two column layout with one common vertical scrollbar and two horizontal scrollbars

Tags: html, css

I want to create two column layout with one vertical scrollbar which scrolls content synchronously. Each column in the page should have own horizontal scrollbar which is positioned at the bottom of the window (always visible).

I created the demo

http://plnkr.co/edit/G0bz2zUrVvH7enYDGLiy?p=preview.

This example shows vertical scrollbar as requested, but horizontals scrollbars has wrong position because I must scroll down to see horizontal scroll bars. Right position is fixed at the bottom of the page.

Could you help me? It is possible to achieve this request by using css and html only?

```css
html,
            body,
            .main-container {
              margin: 0;
              height: 100%;
              overflow: hidden;
            }
            
            .main-container {
              overflow-y: scroll;
              width: 100%;
              clear: both;
            }
            
            .sub-container {
              width: 48%;
              min-height: 100%;
              float: left;
              overflow-x: scroll;
              overflow-y: hidden;
            }
            
            .sub-container.new {
              float: right
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
      <div class="main-container">
        <div class="original sub-container">
          <div>
          .. very long multiline text..<br />
          .. very long multiline text..<br />
          .. very long multiline text..<br />
          .. very long multiline text..<br />
          .. very long multiline text..<br />
          .. very long multiline text..<br />
          .. very long multiline text..<br />
          .. very long multiline text..<br />
          .. very long multiline text..<br />
          .. very long multiline text..<br />
          .. very long multiline text..<br />
          .. very long multiline text..<br />
          .. very long multiline text..<br />
          .. very long multiline text..<br />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="new sub-container">
          <div>
          <div>
          .. very long multiline text..<br />
          .. very long multiline text..<br />
          .. very long multiline text..<br />
          .. very long multiline text..<br />
          .. very long multiline text..<br />
          .. very long multiline text..<br />
          .. very long multiline text..<br />
          .. very long multiline text..<br />
          .. very long multiline text..<br />
          .. very long multiline text..<br />
          .. very long multiline text..<br />
          .. very long multiline text..<br />
          .. very long multiline text..<br />
          .. very long multiline text..<br />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `horizontals scrollbars has wrong position` what you mean by this ??

Comment: @jupin you say that both horizontal scrollbars should be at the bottom of the page, but then you complain that the right horizontal scroll bar is at the bottom of the page. You need to clarify on this.

Comment: Not Clear what you are asking.

Comment: The horizontal scrollbars should be positioned at the botom of the page (fixed) and should be always visible. Problem is: If columns contains long text then I must scroll down by vertical scrollbar to see horizontal scrollbars. See plunkr

Comment: I don't know what the use case is, but this seems like very bad UX. Consider using media queries to stack the columns on smaller screen sizes instead.

Comment: I don't think so. This page is for comaparasion of two versions of same document (diff tool) and it is not targeted to small screen.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any solution to do so with only css. You want the horizontal scrollbars always stay at the bottom of the page, your sub-container must have the fixed height 100vh. Then, you use javascript to set the height of sub-container when you scroll down or up. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can put `max-height: 99vh;` on `.sub-container` but then you need to remove the `overflow-y: hidden;` or change it to `overflow-y: auto;` which causes you to have 2 vertical scrollbars.

So no it is not possible without JS.

I cleaned up your code and showing you what I mean in this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/bAVeL8zOu8Ruc9u2YFhI?p=preview